# converting Obj-c to swift, long press gesture

Tags: objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

i can't seem to get this to work, i'm trying to implant a long press gesture on uicollectionview
found this code here in SO, now i just need to convert it to swift, so i can use it probely

obj-c

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    } else {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        UICollectionViewCell* cell =
            [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // do stuff with the cell
    }
}
```

my approach in swift

```
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        return
    }

    let p: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)!
    if (indexPath == nil) {      // Error here 'NSIndexPath' is not convertible to 'UIGestureRecognizerState'
        println("couldn't find index path")

    } else {
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}
```

appreciate any help, it fails at if (indexPath == nil) with the error 'NSIndexPath' is not convertible to 'UIGestureRecognizerState'

Comment: please add to your Q, what failed.

Comment: i wrote the Error in the code... but i'll update

Comment: Ah, i did not see, sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **optional binding** to find out whether an `optional` contains a value. `indexPathForItemAtPoint` returns an optional value.

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)
{
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}
else
{
     println("couldn't find index path")
}
```

Read about optionals in Apple's swift book.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Answer (score 0):

You can also use optional chaining and map over the optional indexpath.

```
let cell = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p).map {
  self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath($0)
}

if let cell = cell {
  // Do something with non-optional cell
} else {
  println("No cell for point")
}
```

The cell variable will be a UICollectionViewCell? (optional) but that is the return type of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` call anyway.

If you can continue with or return the optional cell you can skip the whole `if let` section especially if you don't need to print the error (or do `if cell == nil { println("No cell for point") }`

See this blogpost for some more ways to handle optionals: [How I Handle Optionals In Swift](http://blog.human-friendly.com/how-i-handle-optionals-in-swift)